# Android remove a class inside div

Tags: java, android, html, arrays, android-studio

i'm trying to get the text in the reference class div without getting the text in the inner div.

I just want what's inside a `<div class="class1">` -> "123456789" without taking "abcdefg".

```
<div class="class0"> 
 <div class="class1"> 
  <div class="class2">
      abcdefg      
  </div> 
   123456789
 </div> 
</div>
```

i tried to run this but it always takes the text i don't want

```
String text = doc.getElementsByClass("class1").html();
String text2 = text.replaceAll("</?div[^>]*>","");
Log.d("text2", text2 );

output:
abcdefg      
123456789
```

but I just want 123456789
how can I do? thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
text = document.getElementsByClassName("class1");
text[0].outerText.split('\n')[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved now by myself

```
doc.select("div.class2").first().remove();
String text = doc.getElementsByClass("class1").html();
```